# What are string matching algorithms used in text editors like Atom and sublime

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, string-matching

I know there are many algorithms for finding a pattern in a text like Boyer Moore, KMP, RabinKarp and so on.

I want to know what is the one that is mostly prefered by text editors and IDEs, as I find them efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Since Emacs is the superior editor, you can take a look in the source code yourself:  [search.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/search.c#n1722)

Emacs uses the [Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm), so that's probably what you should prefer too.